# How to add a DataFrame column consisting of the sum of another column from 2 different DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 2 DataFrames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['n2', 'n4', 'n9', 'n5', 'n6', 'n3', 'n12', 'n19'],
                    'col2': [1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n12', 'n53'],
                   'col2': [4, 7, 1, 4, 7, 1, 9, 0, 3]})
```

both have different amount of rows, let's assume that `col1` is the names to which the values are assigned.

`df2` is carrying an update for `df1` with some updated and some new values and by doing the following:

```
exc = df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])
updated = pd.concat((df1[~exc], df2), ignore_index=True)
print(updated)
```

I'm able to retrieve a new DataFrame consisting of the **updated** \ **unapdated** and **new** values.

```
   col1  col2
0    n9     5
1   n19     1
2    n1     4
3    n2     7
4    n3     1
5    n4     4
6    n5     7
7    n6     1
8    n7     9
9   n12     0
10  n53     3
```

Now if I wanted to add another column `col3` to the `updated`

which will be the sum of `df1['col2']` and `df2['col2']`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
updated['col3'] = prev_df[exc]['col2'] + new_df['col2']
```

But it's clearly not the correct answer:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    n9     5   5.0
1   n19     1  12.0
2    n1     4   NaN
3    n2     7   6.0
4    n3     1  10.0
5    n4     4   6.0
6    n5     7  11.0
7    n6     1   NaN
8    n7     9   NaN
9   n12     0   NaN
10  n53     3   NaN
```

Is there an efficient way to do it without merging or perhaps something close to what I tried?
I know I can set `col1` as index but I'm still not sure how to perform the calculation and maintain the correct rows for each of the `col3` values without making a mess.

I'd love to hear some suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: `merge` אחלה פונקציה. מה הבעיה איתה?

Comment: Check indexes. How do you merge? By column col1?

Comment: @Aryerez Won't it impact the performance when itterating over large dataframes + reshaping multiple time compared to itterating and reshaping once when you know what has to be rashaped?

Comment: Check indexes. How do you merge? By column col1?

Comment: @Alexey Yes by ``col1``

Comment: Why you don't want to merge?

Comment: @Pygirl Because I think it will affect performance compared to itterating and than reshaping, or won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this??

```
x = df1.merge(df2, on='col1', how='outer')
x['col3'] = x.filter(like='col2_').sum(axis=1)
x['col2_y'] = x.col2_y.fillna(x.col2_x)
res = x.drop('col2_x', axis=1).rename(columns={'col2_y':'col2'})
```

---

**res:**

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   n2  7.0 8.0
1   n4  4.0 9.0
2   n9  5.0 5.0
3   n5  7.0 9.0
4   n6  1.0 4.0
5   n3  1.0 6.0
6   n12 0.0 2.0
7   n19 1.0 1.0
8   n1  4.0 4.0
9   n7  9.0 9.0
10  n53 3.0 3.0
```

Comment: Yeah I guess, Thanks! still tho, I'm pretty concerd about how multiple reshapings might affect performance in terms of speed when dealing with big datasets compared to only one when you already have all the necessary values

Comment: @TomerPoliakov How big it will be?. If it's too big I can only think of pyspark based solution not using pandas.

Comment: About 20 wide 1000 high,  and the caculations will have to happen every second, perhaps converting it to C might do the trick